# How do I restore the position of the terminal in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to have VS Code's terminal open at the bottom, and I really liked it. But now, I don't know what I pressed, but the terminal starts up on the left side of the screen. How do I change it?[image]

I tried searching it up in settings but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you aligned the panel to the left and then dragged the terminal panel to a split.

Right click the title bar of the Panel area (the part to the right of "PROBLEMS OUTPUT ..."), and then click "Panel Position" > "Bottom".

Then drag the "TERMINAL" panel handle back into the Panel tab strip in the Panel's title bar.